# Pause between animations

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of < li > elements which I want to animate one after the other, so what I'm doing is the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var i=-1;
var items = $('li');
animateAll();
```

The animateAll() function goes like this

```
function animateAll(){
  i++;
  if(i<items.length){
   var cual=items[i];
   $(cual).css("position", "absolute");
   var xPos=0;//to set the horizontal position
   var yPos=0;//vertical position
   var xInicial=$('#rec_int').position().left;//initial x position
   var xFinal=xInicial+$('#rec_int').innerWidth();
   var yInicial=$('#rec_int').position().top;
   var yFinal=yInicial+$('#rec_int').innerHeight();
   xPos=randomXToY(xInicial,xFinal);
   yPos=randomXToY(yInicial,yFinal);
   $(cual).css("top",xPos).css("left", yPos);
   $(cual).delay(1000).animate({
   left: parseInt($(cual).css('left'),10) == 0 ?    -$(cual).outerWidth() :0,
   top: parseInt($(cual).css('top'),10) == 0 ? -$(cual).outerHeight() : 0
   },1000,animateAll());
}
```

The problem is that all the  < li > are being animated after a 1 second delayed, all at the same time. What I want to achieve, is first move the first "< li >" then the second and so on.
Hope someone can help

Comment: You have an iterator there, so in the delay, use delay(1000*i), that way the delay is 1 second after the previous one, 1000 * 0 = instant, 1000 * 1 = 1 second, 1000 * 2 = 2 seconds, 1000 * 3 = 3 seconds, and so on. this should fix it for the time being

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the delay, since you are delaying each one by 1 second, they will all animate at the same time.

There are many ways to solve this.

1. The easiest way given the setup you have, is to use `$(cual).delay(1000*i).animate({...`
2. The *better* solution, in my opinion, is to use a callback to issue the next animation.  Then you wouldn't even have a delay.  Instead, the next animation would be triggered as soon as the one before it finished.
3. You could try using jquery [queue()](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) on the ul/ol parent.

Comment: Good to hear.  Show your appreciation and show others that you have an answer, by accepting the answer (checkmark to the left).

Answer (score 0):

Its because you also grab all the items. I suggest you start with the first li using this:

```
var start = $('li:first-element');
```

The second step is to make your function recursive so that it repeats itself until all siblings in your list are handled. The function stops when it reaches the last one

```
var start = $('li:first-element');
var currentSibling = start;

function animateAll() {
  //First the delay
  //Do something with the sibling in this area

  //If not last child, repeat and goto next sibling
  if(currentSibling != $('li:last-child')) {
    currentSibling = currentSibling.nextSibling;
    animateAll(); //Recursive
  }
}
```